# VMWare VCenter connection using REST API

Tags: rest, vmware, vcenter

We are developing an application in which we need to integrate different cloud services. We need to connect to VmWare VCenter server and should do the provisioning. Is there any Rest API calls to execute the task?

Thanks.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, the vSphere API is largely SOAP based.
The simplest way to consume our API is via one of the existing SDKs.

For example, you can use the Python SDK (https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi) to perform most vSphere functions via the Python library.

Alternatively, you can use a configuration management platform like Chef via the vSphere specific plugin.  For Chef, there is a vSphere Knife:  https://github.com/chef-partners/knife-vsphere

If you tell us more about the problem you are trying to solve and the tools you are using, we can give you a more detailed answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, We are running our application in nodejs and while searching we found one module named node-vsphere-soap that has limited access on vcenter. What we want is, is there any REST api provided by vcenter(vsphere) to execute provisioning of virtual machines. Any information would be grateful.

Comment: No, not at this time.  We are looking at this for a future release.  Would it be acceptable to write the code in JavaScript?  If so, you can use this fling:  https://labs.vmware.com/flings/vsphere-sdk-for-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Since this question was asked and answered VMware has released a vCenter REST API for version 6.5:

> The VMware vSphere Automation SDKs provide support for your client application infrastructure with services to perform management operations in your vSphere environment. The vSphere Automation SDK for REST also contains samples to demonstrate how to use the new APIs.
>
> The version 6.5 SDK enables programmatic access to the following
>   services:
>
> - Session management
> - Tagging
> - Content Library
> - Virtual Machines
> - vCenter Server Appliance management

Read more:

[vSphere Automation SDK for REST 6.5 Release Notes](http://pubs.vmware.com/Release_Notes/en/developer/vsphere-automation/65/vsphere-automation-sdk-65-rest-release-notes.html?__utma=207178772.1712512638.1486047688.1486047688.1486047688.1&__utmb=207178772.0.10.1486047688&__utmc=207178772&__utmx=-&__utmz=207178772.1486047688.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)%7Cutmccn=(direct)%7Cutmcmd=(none)&__utmv=-&__utmk=182514469#overview)

http://creativeview.co.uk/VMware-vCenter-REST-API-Part-1/

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless 
if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site 
just disappears... **:-(** Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy 
the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing 
your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! **;-)** You can always 
leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your 
material...

Comment: I am trying to use the .Net SDK, but it only works as a console application. I am unable to get it working inside a web application. Can you give any advice?